# "make menuconfig" throwing cannot find -lc error in my Fedora 11 PC

Tags: linux, make

When i try to do a `make menuconfig` in  a Fedora 11 machine it is throwing the following error message:

```
[root@PC04 kernel]# make menuconfig
  HOSTCC  -static scripts/basic/fixdep
scripts/basic/fixdep.c: In function âtrapsâ:
scripts/basic/fixdep.c:377: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
scripts/basic/fixdep.c:379: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 1
make: *** [scripts_basic] Error 2
```

Please help me on this issue? How can i solve this?

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 1):

Install glibc-devel packages, should be fine then

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if you want to do development work on Fedora, run

```
sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```